# news URL scheme format

Tags: url, url-scheme, uri-scheme

I've come across an unusual URL scheme format, namely `news`. What is this scheme used for and what are its pros? Im reading an old book and it could be that this is not used anymore.

Example: `news:rec.arts startrek`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All URI schemes are registered at http://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes.

For `news`, which is described with "USENET news", the corresponding specification is [**RFC 5538:** The 'news' and 'nntp' URI Schemes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5538).

From the [background section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5538#section-2):

> The 'news' and 'nntp' URI schemes identify resources on an NNTP server, individual articles, individual newsgroups, or sets of newsgroups.
>
> User agents like Web browsers supporting these schemes use the NNTP protocol to access the corresponding resources.  The details of how they do this, e.g., employing a separate or integrated newsreader, depend on the implementation.
> […]

More information about `news` is given in the section [2.2. 'news' URIs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5538#section-2.2):

> The 'news' URI scheme identifies articles by their worldwide unique "Message-ID", independent of the server and the newsgroup.